# При выводе результата программы в ConEmu модуль не получается обнаружить, хотя всё установленно и находится в папке вместе с python!

Tags: python, sublime-text, модули, openweathermap, conemu

Сам код:

```
import tyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('42a18a0a4531b7481c304b97a2552365')

place = input('В каком городе/стране?: ')

observation = owm.weather_at_place('')
w = observation.get_waether()
print(w)
```

Результат:

```
D:\depython>weather.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\depython\weather.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tyowm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tyowm'
```

Comment: Очевидная же ошибка... Измените на `import pyowm`

Comment: @nomnoms12 это я ошибся при переписи. Там pyowm но ошибка та же

Comment: Вы же привели Traceback. В нём написано, что Вы пытаетесь в 1 строке сделать следующее: `import tyowm`.

Comment: Предполагаю, что вы исправили в редакторе, но не сохранили в файл. По этому ошибка та же самя

Comment: Откатил вопрос к первой версии. Вписывать ответ в вопрос не рекомендуется, для этого предназначены ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки:

1. Импортирование несуществующего модуля (исправил на `pyowm`)
2. Вызов функции с пустой строкой (исправил на `place`)
3. Вызов несуществующей функции (исправил на `get_weather`)

Также, я указал `language="ru"`.

***Код:***

```py
import pyowm


owm = pyowm.OWM('42a18a0a4531b7481c304b97a2552365', language="ru")

place = input('В каком городе/стране?: ')

observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.get_weather()

print(w)
```

Comment: всё равно ошибка в вызове несуществующего модуля(

Comment: @x1enn Может, Вы забыли его установить?

Comment: @x1enn Введите в консоль (или терминал): `pip install pyowm`

Comment: все модули как python и pip и всё остальное я переустанавливал уже несколько раз и несколько раз перепроверил все на местах все модули в лежат в своих папках

Comment: @x1enn Тогда приведите Вашу ошибку. Этот код я запустил у себя, и он отлично отработал.

Comment: @nomnomus12 моя ошибка выше в результате

Comment: @nomnomus12 Всё не настолько плохо)

Comment: @x1enn Ошибка, которую Вы только что обновили, говорит о том, что у Вас нет модуля `pyowm`. Вы точно уверены, что команда `pip install pyowm` (которую нужно ввести в консоли) исполнилась без ошибок?

Comment: @nomnomus12 я уверен все файлы на месте я весь вечер не могу понять что не так это не только с этим модулем со всеми

Comment: @x1enn С этого и нужно было начинать. Это совсем другой вопрос. Могу посоветовать проверить пути, по которым Python пытается искать Ваши модули: `import sys; print(sys.path)`. Если у Вас не работает поиск модулей, то разберитесь сначала с ним, а потом вернитесь к конкретно этому коду и проверьте его.

Comment: @nomnomus12 разобрался со всем, спасибо)

Comment: @x1enn Расскажите, что случилось, интересно же :) Если мой ответ неверный, то опубликуйте свой.